# Can this definite integral be solved?If so, how?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_{\pi\over4}^{\pi\over2}\sqrt{-\cos(2x)}\,dx$$ I tried everything, from substitution over tangents to duplication trig functions, can anyone give it a try that believes they can do it?

Comment: You forgot your differential.

Comment: looks [very ugly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+pi%2F4+to+pi%2F2+sqrt%28-cos%282x%29%29+dx)

Comment: It's pretty close to a definition of an elliptic integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $-\cos(2x) =2\sin^2x-1$.  Then the integral is

$$\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{-\cos (2x)} \;dx&=\int \sqrt{2\sin^2 x-1} \,dx\\\\
&=i\int \sqrt{1-2\sin^2 x} \,dx\\\\
&=i\;\text{E}(x,\sqrt{2})+C
\end{align}$$

where $\text{E}(x,k)$ is the incomplete elliptical integral of the second kind.